# How to list items with v-for in an associative array? Vue

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am strugling listing `items` with `v-for` on an associative `array`.

Don't know how to pass the `key's` of the `array's` and then list the `titles`.

Found a lot of examples, but didn't found a familiar example.

There are more language selections, but posted just a few so you could all get the idea.

Array:

```
data: () => ({
        translations: [
            {
                'lt': {
                    title: 'Lithuanian',
                },
                'en': {
                    title: 'English',
                }
            }
        ],
})
```

HTML:

```
<select v-model="activeLanguage">
  <option v-for="(translation, key) in translations" :value="key">
    {{translation.title}}
  </option>
</select>
```

How to specify the `key` and then display the `titles` in a `v-for` and in a `HTML option` tag?

Comment: Can you change the variable `translations` and edit it so it's an object and not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<option v-for="(translation, key) in translations[0]" :value="key">
  {{ translation.title }}
</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, and is very simple. Had a thought of doing this way, but didn't do it, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over `translations[0]` instead. Here is an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
         activeLanguage:null,
         translations: [
            {
                'lt': {
                    title: 'Lithuanian',
                },
                'en': {
                    title: 'English',
                }
            }
        ],
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <select v-model="activeLanguage">
          <option v-for="(translation, key) in translations[0]" :value="key">
                {{translation.title}}
          </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, but this is not the proper solution.
There will be multiple languages, and the select purpess is to select the language and then change the page content by the selected language.
Made is as simple as possible, so posted just the part where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)